# How to install Turicreate in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, turi-create

I know Google Colaboratory python version is 3.9.16, and Turicreate only works for 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8. So how can I use turicrate in google colab?

I've tried:

```
!pip install virtualenv
!virtualenv -p python3.7 env
!source env/bin/activate
!pip install turicreate
```

But I always get this error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting turicreate
  Downloading turicreate-6.4.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: turicreate
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for turicreate (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for turicreate
  Running setup.py clean for turicreate
Failed to build turicreate
Installing collected packages: turicreate
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for turicreate did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Running setup.py install for turicreate ... error
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> turicreate

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the version of python you are using in google colab?

Comment: Yes, but from what I've seen it's not possible to change the Python version in Colab. So that's why I tried to use virtualenv, but I got nothing.